# xmltextreader in visual basic display data in label

Tags: xml, windows

I need help to take xml data from a url and then display certain information from the xml data to various labels in visual basic application form.

Code:

```
Dim strUrl As String = "URL"
        Dim wrGETURL As WebRequest
        wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(strUrl)
        Dim objStream As Stream
        objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse.GetResponseStream()
        Dim reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(strUrl)
        While reader.Read()
????

        End While
```

I'm stuck at this point.